# Which of overload templates will be call?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have some doubt, I writing some code(for receive the naked pointer), in C++ something like this:

```
template< typename T >
auto unwrap_ptr(T smart_ptr){
    //if it some class which store pointer
    //receive this pointer with method get()
    return smart_ptr.get();
}

template< typename T >
auto unwrap_ptr(T *nake_ptr){
    //if it naked(simple) pointer return this pointer
    return nake_ptr;
}
```

If it function take naked pointer it return this pointer, in otherwise it return ptr from get() method.
And after check it in my mind appear doubt. In my machine and compiler it will work, but what about other compiler? What say about this situation standard? It is UB? Will be in some case call first function if I put in function naked pointer? And second little question(sorry that they are in one place) what will be here

```
template< typename T >
bool same_type(T x, T y) {
    //if x and y same type(class) return true
    return true;
}


template< typename X, typename Y >
bool same_type(X x, Y y) {
    //if x and y different type(class) return false
    return false;
}
```

It will be work how I think or in some cases it will be dangerous code?

Comment: At least it is certainly not UB. UB is not about something like this ...

Comment: One question per question please!

Comment: @L.F. Are you suuuure? :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think this is more of a compile time issue :P

Comment: Off-topic: C++20 introduces [`std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) which may be of interest.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry by this, but it similar question, so I couldn't stop myself

Comment: @L.F. Nais; stolen for teh answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If it function take naked pointer it return this pointer, in oterwise it return ptr from get() method. And after chek it in my mind appear doubt. In my machine and compiler it will work, but what about other compiler? What say about this situation standart? It is UB? Will be in some case call first function if I put in function naked pointer?

This approach is reasonable, well-defined and portable. No UB!

However, it is limited in that you won't be able to pass a `unique_ptr` in, because a `unique_ptr` cannot be copied. Consider taking `const T&` into the first function, then add another one that takes `const T&&` but is deleted (to protect against temporaries, for which this function is very dangerous due to the probable dangling pointer!).

```
template< typename T >
auto unwrap_ptr(const T& smart_ptr){
    //if it some class wich store pointer
    //receive this pointer with method get()
    return smart_ptr.get();
}

template< typename T >
auto unwrap_ptr(const T&& smart_ptr) = delete;

template< typename T >
auto unwrap_ptr(T *nake_ptr){
    //if it naked(simple) pointer return this pointer
    return nake_ptr;
}

#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto sptr = std::make_unique<int>(42);
    int x = 43;

    unwrap_ptr(sptr); // ok
    //unwrap_ptr(std::make_unique<int>(42));  // prohibited
    unwrap_ptr(&x); // ok
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb6b8ab672a659d6))

C++20 will have [`std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) which does the same thing, though at first glance it doesn't seem to have the above protection against temporaries which is a shame. It's probably a case of "let the programmer deal with this problem, if they need to"; ultimately, you are going to have to be careful about the lifetime of the returned raw pointer anyway.

---

> And second little question(sorry that they are in one place) what will be here
>   It will be work how I think or in some cases it will be dangerous code?

Yes, that's fine too.

However we would typically use [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) for this. To bring deduction back into it you could wrap it:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename X, typename Y>
bool same_type(const X&, const Y&)
{
   return std::is_same_v<X, Y>;
}
```

Comment: Taking `T&&` is dangerous.  You could call `get` in a pointer that gets destroyed when the function exits.  taking `T const&` and adding a `T&&` case that is deleted will fix that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm [doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/981e865f44cff0fd)

Comment: Oops.  Needs to be `auto unwrap_ptr(const T&& smart_ptr) = delete;`.  Otherwise `T&&` is still a better match for a non const lvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay, think we're on the money now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Nice answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for answer, I forgot that somebody can use unique_ptr, it my slip, about is_same, I know, but in some case it will be not beautiful code: is_same< decltype(Myobject1), decltype(Myobject2) >

Comment: @emik_g `template <typename X, typename Y> bool same_type(const X&, const Y&) { return std::is_same_v<X, Y>; }` isn't so bad ;) Added that to the answer.